# How can you show a ul list by clicking a link and then change the source?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm making a page where I have three category lists where I want to use jQuery to show the children items of a single list when a user clicks on the parent list item. See screenshot (clicking on men show the items below).

[image: category list items]

Now when the page is loaded there is no link `href="#"` on the parent item. But when a user clicks on it and the list opens, it should change the link to the 'men' category. I made a jsfiddle to show you what I currently have. However with the jquery below, the link stays at `"#"`.

```
$("#cat-item25").click(function () {
    $("#child1").show('slow');
    $(this).attr('src', '/product-category/men/');
});
```

[Here is the JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Malachute/P8RHv/1/)

Comment: You'r assigning the "src" attribute, while you want the "href" to change. Obvious why that can't work? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to change the link's `href`.  The `src` attribute is for images.

```
$("#cat-item25").click(function () {
    $("#child1").show('slow');
    $(this).attr('href', '/product-category/men/');
    return false;
});
```

The `return false;` is so that it doesn't go to `/product-category/men/` immediately.

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/uPMPj/2/).

Answer (score 3):

You're changing the wrong attribute, you need to use `href` not `src`

```
$("#cat-item25").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#child1").show('slow');
    $(this).attr('href', '/product-category/men/');
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/P8RHv/2/